# How to verify the manager.tz script code?

Tags: smart-contracts, security, verification

Since the protocol update to Babylon all KT1 accounts were replaced with smart contracts which contain the `manager.tz` script.

Code:

```
parameter
  (or
     (lambda %do unit (list operation))
     (unit %default));
storage key_hash;
code
  { UNPAIR ;
    IF_LEFT
      { # 'do' entrypoint
        # Assert no token was sent:
        # to send tokens, the default entry point should be used
        PUSH mutez 0 ;
        AMOUNT ;
        ASSERT_CMPEQ ;
        # Assert that the sender is the manager
        DUUP ;
        IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT ;
        ADDRESS ;
        SENDER ;
        ASSERT_CMPEQ ;
        # Execute the lambda argument
        UNIT ;
        EXEC ;
        PAIR ;
      }
      { # 'default' entrypoint
        DROP ;
        NIL operation ;
        PAIR ;
      }
  };
```

or (source: better-call.dev):

```
{ 
  { { DUP ; CAR ; DIP { CDR } } }  ;
  IF_LEFT { 
    PUSH mutez "0.000000 ꜩ"  ;
    AMOUNT  ;
    { 
      { COMPARE ; EQ }  ;
      IF { } 
      $ELSE { { UNIT ; FAILWITH } } 
    }  ;
    { DIP { DUP } ; SWAP }  ;
    IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT  ;
    ADDRESS  ;
    SENDER  ;
    { 
      { COMPARE ; EQ }  ;
      IF { } 
      $ELSE { { UNIT ; FAILWITH } } 
    }  ;
    UNIT  ;
    EXEC  ;
    PAIR 
  } 
  $ELSE { DROP ; NIL operation; PAIR } 
}
```

The formal proof `manager.v`:

```
(* Open Source License *)
(* Copyright (c) 2019 Nomadic Labs. <contact@nomadic-labs.com> *)

(* Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a *)
(* copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), *)
(* to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation *)
(* the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, *)
(* and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the *)
(* Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions: *)

(* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included *)
(* in all copies or substantial portions of the Software. *)

(* THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR *)
(* IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, *)
(* FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL *)
(* THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER *)
(* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING *)
(* FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER *)
(* DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. *)


Require Import String.
Require Import Michocoq.macros.
Import syntax.
Import comparable.
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import semantics.
Require Import util.
Import error.
Require List.
Require Import Lia.

Definition parameter_ty := or (lambda unit (list operation)) unit.
Definition storage_ty := key_hash.

Module ST : (SelfType with Definition self_type := parameter_ty).
  Definition self_type := parameter_ty.
End ST.

Module manager(C:ContractContext)(E:Env ST C).

Module semantics := Semantics ST C E. Import semantics.

Definition manager : full_contract _ ST.self_type storage_ty :=
  (UNPAIR ;;
   IF_LEFT
   ( (* 'do' entrypoint *)
     (* Assert no token was sent: *)
     (* to send tokens, the default entry point should be used *)
     PUSH mutez (0 ~mutez) ;;
     AMOUNT ;;
     ASSERT_CMPEQ ;;
     (* Assert that the sender is the manager *)
     DUUP ;;
     IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT ;;
     ADDRESS ;;
     SENDER ;;
     ASSERT_CMPEQ ;;
     (* Execute the lambda argument *)
     UNIT ;;
     EXEC ;;
     PAIR
   )
   ( (* 'default' entrypoint *)
     DROP1 ;;
     NIL operation ;;
     PAIR
   )
  ).

Definition manager_spec
           (storage : data storage_ty)
           (param : data parameter_ty)
           (new_storage : data storage_ty)
           (returned_operations : data (list operation))
           (fuel : Datatypes.nat) :=
  match param with
  | inr tt =>
    (* %default: anybody can send tokens this does not modify the
    storage and produces no operation. *)
    new_storage = storage /\ returned_operations = nil
  | inl (existT _ _ lam) =>
    (* %do is only available to the stored manager and rejects non-null amounts*)
    amount env = (0 ~Mutez) /\
    sender env = address_ env unit (implicit_account env storage) /\
    new_storage = storage /\
    eval (no_self env) lam fuel (tt, tt) = Return _ (returned_operations, tt)
  end.

Lemma eqb_eq a c1 c2 :
  BinInt.Z.eqb (comparison_to_int (compare a c1 c2)) Z0 = true <->
  c1 = c2.
Proof.
  rewrite BinInt.Z.eqb_eq.
  rewrite comparison_to_int_Eq.
  apply comparable.compare_eq_iff.
Qed.

Lemma eqb_neq a c1 c2 :
  BinInt.Z.eqb (comparison_to_int (compare a c1 c2)) Z0 = false <->
  c1 <> c2.
Proof.
  split.
  - intros H He.
    apply eqb_eq in He.
    congruence.
  - intro Hneq.
    rewrite <- eqb_eq in Hneq.
    generalize (BinInt.Z.eqb (comparison_to_int (compare a c1 c2)) Z0) Hneq.
    intros []; congruence.
Qed.

Lemma and_right {P Q R : Prop} : P -> (Q <-> R) -> (Q <-> (P /\ R)).
Proof.
  intuition.
Qed.

Lemma and_both {P Q R : Prop} : (Q <-> R) -> ((P /\ Q) <-> (P /\ R)).
Proof.
  intuition.
Qed.

Lemma fold_eval_precond fuel :
  @eval_precond_body (@semantics.eval_precond fuel) =
  @semantics.eval_precond (S fuel).
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma if_false_is_and (b : Datatypes.bool) P : (if b then P else false) <-> b = true /\ P.
Proof.
  destruct b.
  - intuition.
  - simpl.
    intuition discriminate.
Qed.

Lemma manager_correct
      (storage : data storage_ty)
      (param : data parameter_ty)
      (new_storage : data storage_ty)
      (returned_operations : data (list operation))
      (fuel : Datatypes.nat) :
  fuel >= 42 ->
  eval env manager (13 + fuel) ((param, storage), tt) = Return _ ((returned_operations, new_storage), tt)
  <-> manager_spec storage param new_storage returned_operations fuel.
Proof.
  intro Hfuel.
  remember (13 + fuel) as fuel2.
  assert (30 <= fuel2) by lia.
  rewrite return_precond.
  rewrite eval_precond_correct.
  unfold manager_spec.
  do 5 (more_fuel; simpl).
  destruct param as [(tff, lam)|[]].
  - do 5 (more_fuel; simpl).
    simpl.
    rewrite if_false_is_and.
    rewrite (eqb_eq mutez).
    apply and_both.
    do 5 (more_fuel; simpl).
    rewrite if_false_is_and.
    rewrite (eqb_eq address).
    apply and_both.
    simpl in Heqfuel2.
    repeat rewrite fold_eval_precond.
    assert (fuel = S (S fuel2)) by lia.
    subst fuel. clear Hfuel.
    rewrite <- eval_precond_correct.
    rewrite precond_exists.
    unfold precond_ex.
    split.
    ++ intros ((ops, []), (Hops, Hs)).
       injection Hs; intros; subst.
       auto.
    ++ intros ([], Hlam).
       exists (returned_operations, tt).
       auto.
  - simpl.
    intuition congruence.
Qed.

End manager.
```

How can a community member verify this with "Mi-Cho-Coq" by himself? Is there an **easy** way like an online site where you can paste the Michelson code and the proof and then somehow see the checks, verify the outputs and something like code coverage or something like unit-tests? I would like to know which aspects of the code are being tested and which different states it can have, as I am unable to understand the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to check the proof

Currently, the only way to check the proof is to install and run the Coq proof assistant on the manager.tz file. This is automated in the continuous integration script of the Mi-Cho-Coq project so you can see it [here](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/mi-cho-coq/pipelines).

In the future, we plan to use [JsCoq](https://x80.org/rhino-coq/) to run Mi-Cho-Coq proofs from web browsers.

## What is proved

The family of properties that can be proved in Mi-Cho-Coq are of the "functional verification" family. This means that we characterize the effect of a single execution of the smart contract. For the manager contract, the relation between inputs and outputs is defined by the `manager_spec` relation defined at the beginning of the Coq file and the correctness proof is the last `Lemma` (`manager_correct`) of the Coq file.

## How to check that the proven contract is the one that is deployed on-chain

The Mi-Cho-Coq version of the manager script is defined in the begining of the Coq file. Mi-Cho-Coq syntax was designed to be close to Michelson's one but a few syntactic differences remain; among others:

- semicolons are doubled in Mi-Cho-Coq
- curly braces are replaced by parentheses

The manager script in Michelson syntax is also published alongside the proof in the `src/contracts` directory of Mi-Cho-Coq. So verifying that the certified script matches the on-chain contract can be split in two steps:

- check that the only differences between the Coq and the Michelson versions of the script are the purely syntactic ones I explained above;
- check that the Michelson script in the Mi-Cho-Coq repository and the one on the chain match.

To automate the first check, I recently implemented a Michelson lexer, parser, macro-expander, and type-checker in Coq. The second check could also be automated in the future.